# connect search bar with functionality to chained select data

Tags: java, jquery, select

I got this issue beacuse i newbis with Java  i make this catalogue with Java and html with show information in table about product . Now all i want to do is to add search bar next to this select and find this product by id or name or value and show same information like in table by select jquery . Can somebody help mi with this its.. important to me . 
Important : For now work only Ciezarowe ---> BOVA ---> all in bova. When you open site and it dosent work try to referesh should help .
I wanna add something like this

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/cristoferdomingues/KR7KV/10/][1]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use select 2 javascript libray https://select2.github.io/

Comment: I wanna separately select and search , but at the same time they show product infom in table